# Detect browser refresh in an Angular project

Tags: angular, routes, refresh

I want to detect when a page is refreshed using a router  in my [single-page application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) (Angular project).

Is there an alternate way?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this:

```
  this.router.events
    .pipe(filter((rs): rs is NavigationEnd => rs instanceof NavigationEnd))
    .subscribe(event => {
      if (
        event.id === 1 &&
        event.url === event.urlAfterRedirects
      ) {
          // Your code here for when the page is refreshd
      }
    })
```

You will need to import

```
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { Router  } from '@angular/router';
```

Comment: I used this code and it worked for me the first two times (i am able to execute some code when user clicks refresh button) but it suddenly stopped working (my mentionned code is not executed anymore) and i did not change anything since. So how is this happening ?. I am using Firefox 71.0

Comment: I assume you are using `import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators'`

Comment: @DeadlyChambers, yes ```import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';```

Comment: does this really works? because in my application I am checking on `unload` event so I want to know if using angular routing do the same thing

Comment: There is no event.id in Angular 13.

Answer (score 34):

In the *component.ts* file:

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

export let browserRefresh = false;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {

  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.subscription = router.events.subscribe((event) => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
          browserRefresh = !router.navigated;
        }
    });
  }
```

In the page you need:

```
import { browserRefresh } from '../app.component';
```

....

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.browserRefresh = browserRefresh;
    console.log('refreshed?:', browserRefresh);
  }
```

See a working example at https://stackblitz.com/edit/refreshangular?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpage-a%2Fpage-a.component.ts

Click on page A and Page B. Refresh to see the difference.

[image: Click on page A and Page B. Refresh to see the difference2]

Comment: Nice!  The StackBlitz made your solution easy to understand.

Comment: Nice, but I'll implement as a service rather than an import from app.component because will cause a performance issue on large applications

Comment: How is this supposed to solve it? router.navigated is alway false. No matter you type the url to new tab or you refresh it. Also in stackblitz console it writes true in both cases.

Comment: @char 5 I edit the question. You need to click on page A or B to see that doesn't refresh and then if you refresh or type url will be refresh= true

Comment: thanks! I understand but here typing the url i.e starting new session and refreshing session are the same. at least i would like to know if the existing session is refreshed. this is not solution for that. it can be done in most browsers but i haven't found a way that works in Safari

Comment: @charm I am using Safari.Yes typing the url or refreshing session, are the same.  To change page by routing (click button Page B) is not refreshing.  I don't understand what you need?

Comment: To detect the broser refresh like the title says. This happens when user has a session like myapp:4200/pageX and hits F5 or browser's Refresh button. Then it shoukd get back to myapp:4200/pageX and  detect that the existing session was refreshed. My app is quite complex and i need to know. Other browsers provide this info by calling performance.getEntriesByType('navigation'). In Safari the array is empty.

Answer (score 5):

An Angular application is a single-page application, and in the context of a single-page application the full app is loaded once, and data or screens are refreshed as the user uses your application.

A browser refresh is the equivalent of shutting down your application and launching it again.  There isn’t any default way to respond to this inside your Angular application.

You might be able to mock something up using [onBeforeUnload()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) to log that the application was reloaded; and then check that log in your application's initialization routine to perform some special action.

Comment: If you're using sessionStorage the session remains and if your app is using this sessionStorage then it's not the same as shutting down and launching, because sessionStorage will persist between reloads. It only gets cleaned either manually or when the window(/tab) closes.

Answer (score 3):

The newest way in Angular 7 and later is that we can now add route navigation properties.

So if `/somepage` is the page we want to detect and if the browser was refreshed, we set the *navigate* property *prevPage* when we go to this page:

```
this.router.navigate(['/somepage'], { state: { prevPage: this.router.url } });
```

Then inside *somepage*:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    const previousUrl = history.state.prevPage ?? null;
    if (!this.previousUrl) {
      console.log('page was refreshed!');
    } else {
      console.log('I came here from: ', previousUrl);
    }
}
```

**Note:** This works if you want to detect browser refresh from a specific page.

If you need this throughout the site then I would go with a different approach.

Comment: Not an ideal solution...!

Comment: @VikramSapate Why is this not an ideal solution? Just saying that its not ideal does no one any good and makes people question the above answer without knowing why. 
You should provide constructive criticism or don't say anything at all.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to detect when page is refresh using router

You add a *top level* resolver to the router. If you have a single top level router, then it will only be resolved once and children will handle page navigation. Each time the resolver is resolved is equal to a page refresh in the browser.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: TopComponent,
    resolve: { loaded: PageLoadedResolver },
    children: [
         ...
    ]
  }
];
```

There are many other ways of detecting a page load event in Angular.

The constructor of your `AppModule`.

```
@NgModule({...})
export class AppModule {
     public constructor() {
          console.log('page loaded');
     }
}
```

A service injected into the root that is used at least once.

```
@Injector({provideIn: 'root'})
export class MyService {
     public constructor() {
          console.log('page loaded');
     }
}
```

There is also the `main.ts` file which bootstraps the Angular application.

```
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
        .then(() => console.log('page loaded'))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Basically, anywhere there is JavaScript that runs once...

Answer (score 2):

The refresh triggers the Scroll event object.

```
class Scroll { type: EventType.Scroll; routerEvent: NavigationEnd | NavigationSkipped;position: [...];anchor: string | null;toString(): string;}
```

I used this object to get the NavigationEnd event:

```
    this.router.events
     .pipe(
       map((event) => (event instanceof Scroll ? event.routerEvent : event)),
      filter((event) => event instanceof ActivationStart || event instanceof NavigationEnd),
      takeUntil(this.destroy$)
     ).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually detect page reloads by checking for two specific router events. Every time the path of the browser changes, Angular router events start firing from [NavigationStart](https://v14.angular.io/api/router/NavigationStart), however, when the page is simply reloaded, only the end events are fired and they start firing from [ActivationEnd](https://v14.angular.io/api/router/ActivationEnd).

To be able to tell whether the page was reloaded or if the user simply navigated to same place within the app I would use this code:

```js
import { Component, inject } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivationEnd, NavigationStart, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { filter, fromEvent, tap } from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-layout',
  templateUrl: './layout.component.html'
})
export class LayoutComponent {
  /* DEPENDENCIES */
  private readonly _router = inject(Router);

  /* MEMBERS */
  constructor() {
    let pageReloaded: {
      started ? : boolean,
      ended ? : boolean
    } = {};

    this._router.events.pipe(
      filter(evt => evt instanceof NavigationStart || evt instanceof ActivationEnd),
      tap(evt => {
        if (evt instanceof NavigationStart) pageReloaded.started = true;
        else pageReloaded.ended = true;
      })
    ).subscribe(evt => {
      if (pageReloaded.started && pageReloaded.ended) console.log('this is a navigation');
      else console.log('this is a page reload');
    });
  }
}
```

It is important to do this from your top component, in my case, I always do it from AppComponent.

**Notice: this only detects whether the load of the page was triggered by navigation or by reload, it does not interfere with either one of this cases**

If what you want is to do something before the page is reloaded, I would recommend using [before unload event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event). I do not know of any native way of doing this in Angular.

I hope this helps someone someday!